# Intellij IDEA doesn't recognize java file: blue square in directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project structure like this:

[image]

```
src (sources root)
---main  
-------java (sources root)
-----------com
--------------requests
----------------------File1.java (needs to be package com.requests)
----------------------File2.java (needs to be package com.requests)
----------------------File3.java (needs to be package com.requests)
--------------things
--------------util
--------------web
-------resources
----------------images
-------webapp
-------------WEB-INF
--------------------classes
---------------------------com
------------------------------requests
------------------------------things
------------------------------util
------------------------------web
---------------------lib
```

However, `File1.java`, `File2.java` and `File3.java` don't seem to be recognized as Java files and I can't compile them:

[image]

Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: In the filesystem, do you have `com` and `requests` as nested directories or just one directory `com.requests` with a dot in the name?

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki They are separate (nested) directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should unmark `src` directory as a source root because it doesn't contain Java code. In your example only `src/main/java` directory should be marked as source root.

You can do it by right clicking on `src` and selecting "Mark Directory as" > "Unmark as Source Root".

Comment: Ok, I did it, but the blue square is still present in `com`'s image and the `.java` files are not recognized ;( Right now it's only `java` that is blue (marked as source root).

Comment: Possibly `com` is marked as an IntelliJ module, I have not idea how could this happen. I'd delete `.idea` and `.iml` files and re-import the project.

Comment: Right, when I create a new directory `coms` and put `requests`, `things`, `util`, `web` in there, everything works fine! Then I delete `com` and create it again and move the packages with files back in there - and I get the error! Must have somthing to do with directory's name - as in, `com`?